# Basic HTTP Authentication

Tags: php, authorization

I am having some difficulties getting the HTTP Authorization to work. For some reason all I keep getting is the popup box asking for the user name and password. This is the code I am using. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong??

```
if (  !isset(  $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']  )  || !isset(  $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']  ) )
{
    authorizeUser();
    //if no result, there is no user
}
else
{
    $user = htmlentities( trim( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ) );
    $pass = htmlentities( trim( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ) );
    $pass = md5( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] );

    //connect to MySQL data here//


    $sql = "SELECT user_name,pwd FROM tableName WHERE user_name='$user' AND pwd='$pass'";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql );
    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0 )
    {
        authorizeUser();
    }
    else
    {
        header( "Location: somepage" );
    }
}

function authorizeUser(  )
{
    header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Area"' );
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized' );
            echo "text if cancel button used";
}//end authorizedUser
```

Comment: When I run the query straight from phpmyadmin, it works fine. I can't tell from the script though.

Comment: What does the print $sql output?

Comment: it returns one result, username and password when this is ran from phpmyadmin

Comment: of course I have to replace $user with an actual user name and password with md5(actual password)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip the SQL injection speech for now, but don't user `htmlentities()` on the password or user before your query.  It's for strings being displayed back to the browser or passed in a url, not for escaping data being compared to SQL results or inserted into DB's.   If a username or password could have a special html character in it encoded, you'd want to decode it with  `html_entity_decode ()` before using it.

Back to injection protection... to protect against injection without moving to prepared statements via mysqli or pdo, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` in place of `htmlentities()`;

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string( html_entity_decode (trim( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ) ));
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string( html_entity_decode (trim( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ) ));
$pass = md5( $pass );
```

Comment: I made these changes, but my problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an issue as you are simply setting the value of $pass twice,

```
$pass = htmlentities( trim( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ) );
$pass = md5( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] );
```

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
$pass = htmlentities( trim( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ) );
$pass = md5( $pass );
```

Comment: I am replacing the value, if you look closer I am taking the value of $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] using htmlentities and trim functions and assigning it to $pass. The 2nd line replaces that value with the md5 of the preceding $pass. OOOOOhhhh crap, I see it now.....so simple it just eluded me!

Comment: This still did not fix the overall problem though

Comment: This might also be an issue,
`SELECT user_name,pwd FROM tableName WHERE user_name='$user' AND pwd='$pass'"`
try,
`SELECT user_name,pwd FROM tableName WHERE user_name='".$user."' AND pwd='".$pass."'"`